# Azure AD B2C multi step page in custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is It possible to create a multi step sign up custom policy in azure ad b2c ?

I mean I need to capture personal details and verify them against my database if valid? Then second page to create a username and password and store them in azure active directory. 
Since I already have a design implemented for these pages I don't want to change this by using ad b2c.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, see [the Wingtip sample for Azure AD B2C custom policies](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c) which contains [a sign-up or sign-in policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_sign_up_sign_in_games.xml) that includes [multiple orchestration steps](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/d740d68f2f5433883e75f5bc662b661f553d836a/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml#L4389).

You will have to validate the personal details [via a REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw).

Comment: Chris? Is there any way to tackle the below problem? There is as admin portal from which he selects few security questions and also gives the number of security questions to be opted while registration. Now since thus registration and login is taken care by ad b2c I am not sure how can this be achieved.